SOQL Join Query to search for string of text in CASE and CaseComment Objects/tables
Wondering if there is a way to write a SOQL query to search for a string of text in both the CASE object and CaseComment that searches the string of text in the subject, account name and CommentBody fields? Something like these two queries:
Select id, description, subject, status, Account_Name__c
From Case 
WHERE ((Subject LIKE '%Text string%') OR (Account_Name__c  LIKE '%Text string%')
  OR ('%Text string%' LIKE (SELECT CommentBody FROM CaseComment))


Select id, description, subject, status, Assigned_To_Participant_Account__c, Account_Name__c
From Case 
WHERE (Subject LIKE '%Text string%') OR (Account_Name__c  LIKE '%Text string%')
      OR CommentBody LIKE (SELECT CommentBody FROM CaseComment WHERE Commentbody like '%Text string%')


Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  You should use a SOSL query to search for the same text across multiple objects.

check out SOSL in the SOQL/SOSL doc
